# Responding to Ping in Node.JS Server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2, ping

I have a NodeJS server that is running on AWS EC2. For EC2 Health Monitoring, the server needs to respond to Ping requests. I haven't been able to find a way to do so. I've found many express middleware components to send a Ping from the server, but not how to respond to one.

Thank You,
Gary

Comment: ping uses icmp and AFAIK there is nothing in node standard library that supports icmp.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check if you network settings has reply ping enabled ? On the default settings of nodejs, the server has to reply.

[Security risk of PING?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/security-risk-of-ping)

On AWS EC2 : [Enable Ping ICMP Replies For Amazon EC2 Windows Instances](https://web.archive.org/web/20200221140845/http://www.therealtimeweb.com/index.cfm/2011/10/28/amazon-ec2-ping)

On linux : https://www.linux.com/community/blogs/129-servers/18163 / [Ping command basics for testing and troubleshooting](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ping-usage-basics)

Comment: links are broken

Answer (score 1):

After digging some more, I've realized that AWS EC2 Load Balancers are not using Ping for health check, but use a HTTP GET command to access some file (user specified) on the server. If the GET request is successful, then the server is deemed to have responded to the "ping" request. So, all I had to do was to create a really small ping.html file and serve it, when requested.